# Find record of values more that one apart in SQL server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to write a sql statement that will allow me to check each row in a sql server table sequentially. If the values for the fields are more than one apart I would like to return the value of that field and the field that is more than 1 away. For instance, my fields look like this:

**ValueField**

```
V100819493
V100819492
V100819491
V100819232
```

In this case the only values that are more than 1 apart are:

```
V100819232
V100819491
```

Any idea on how I can do this in a select statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this directly in a select statement. Your best bet would be to select the values using an ORDER BY statement, and then loop through them. Check each value against its predecessor and see if the difference > 1.

You could in theory do this all in SQL by writing a function to insert each value which passes the check into a secondary (possibly temporary) table, but if you can, implement the check in C#, Visual Basic, what have you for obvious performance reasons.

Comment: If I go the SQL route would this be done in a while loop? Just a bit more info on this, we had to manually insert 1,000,000 records at a time from our sql DB to a DB in the cloud. The problem is they are now off by a little over a million records so we want to find out which ones are out of sequence, and then reissue the update.

Comment: Yes. Create a temporary table to hold the records which meet the critera and prepare a statement to insert the record into that table. (Because you are going to be doing a ton of inserting, doing a prepared statement ahead of time will give you a peformance boost). Loop through and you'll have a temp table filled with the data you are looking for.

Comment: @Mr_Creosote: You can avoid looping if you do a self-join on the table.

Answer (score 5):

This gets a little easier if you're not doing character-based math operations; I'm making the assumption that every value in this table consists of a single alphabetic character followed by numerals.

```
/* Create sample data */

declare @table Table (ValueField varchar(40))

insert into @table (ValueField)
select 'V100819493'
UNION SELECT 'V100819492'
UNION SELECT 'V100819491'
UNION SELECT 'V100819232'


/* Join table against itself, using a 'staggered' join to join each record to the previous one. */

select * from 

(
    select 
        ValueField as High_Value, 
        CONVERT(BIGINT,SUBSTRING(valuefield, 2, 800)) as Numeric_Value,
        ROW_NUMBER()  over (order by Valuefield) as line 
    from @table 
) t1

left outer join 
(
    select 
        ValueField as Low_Value, 
        CONVERT(BIGINT,SUBSTRING(valuefield, 2, 800)) as Numeric_Value,
        ROW_NUMBER()  over (order by Valuefield) as line 

    from @table 
)t2 on t1.line -1 = t2.line 


where t1.Numeric_Value - t2.Numeric_Value <> 1
```

Comment: +1 Nice solution.  The results would be a little easier to read if instead of `Select *` you just brought back `Select Low_Value AS ValueField, High_Value AS Next_Value`

Comment: Thanks! I left the output a little verbose because I feel it's a little more accessible education-wise; showing everything is something I've found helpful when I'm doing research or walking through a query and wondering 'now why did they do that?'

Something else that strikes me is that you could just join the table with the ValueField to a generic numbers table.

Comment: Your assumption is correct mikurski. The thing is we don't really need to issue the update statement in the sql statement. We already have a BCP command to issue the insert. All we need to figure out is the how to get the field value that is off by more than one.